# Replacing words in a string if its in an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to search the words in a php string and replace any word in the string that is in an array for example:

```
$array = array('john', 'peter', 'andrew', 'james', 'mark'); 
$string = "This is a photo from peter which he sent to mark";
```

Now I want to search all the words in the `$string` and replace any word that is within the `$array` with an image so the `$string` will now look like this:

```
$string = "This is a photo from <img src='peter.jpg'> which he sent to <img src='mark.jpg'>";
```

Please do anyone know an easy way to how I can achieve this?

I don't think it's a duplicate. In that question only a letter or word is replaced but in this case I need to replace any word in the string that is within an array

Comment: `strtr()` accepts an array as argument for the replacement. So it does work for your case.

Comment: Okay so I have to run my replacement in the array like this `array('john'=>'<replacement>', 'peter'=>'<replacement>')`.... and for the rest of the array?

Comment: Yes. And the replacement will be your img tag.

Comment: Thanks so much, I appreciate